# select query results talble

Tags: postgresql

looking for some help with a select query,Not sure how to explain it, I guess its a bit of a transpose and group by? Easier if I just show.

If I have a table like this .

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testbed.OrderingTAB (location text, depar text, pops bigint);

insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('AAA','a-team',20);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('AAA','b-team',240);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('AAA','c-team',767);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('AAA','d-team',33);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('AAA','e-team',344);

insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('BBB','a-team',54);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('BBB','b-team',77);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('BBB','c-team',23);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('BBB','d-team',899);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('BBB','e-team',34);

insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('CCC','a-team',34);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('CCC','b-team',8686);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('CCC','c-team',8877);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('CCC','d-team',45);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('CCC','e-team',20);

insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('DDD','a-team',20);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('DDD','b-team',456);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('DDD','c-team',55);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('DDD','d-team',76);
insert into testbed.OrderingTAB values ('DDD','e-team',34);
```

How can I create a select statement to return the information like this

```
location    A-team  B-team  C-team  D-team  E-team
AAA         20      54      34      20      344
BBB         240     77      8686    456     34
CCC         767     23      8877    55      20
DDD         33      899     45      76      34
```

Comment: Please explain how values in *-team columns calculated? They are not looks as simple pivot

Comment: Is teams count constant?

Comment: You've tagged this as sql and postgresql - which is it?
As Slava has pointed out, pivoting the data you have supplied does not give your expected results, so we will need to know how you calculated them

Comment: Sorry might have confused things. All I meant if I have a table like OrderingTAB, what query would I need to write to create the example output?

Comment: Where does the last value in the E-team come from. It does not appear to be in your data and/or it falls out of synch with your scheme.

Comment: @CHill60: SQL is a query language used by all relational databases. The `sql` tag is perfectly valid. The `sql-server` tag refers to the database product from Microsoft

Answer (score -1):

You can do achieve this result in many ways like `CASE`, `PIVOT` function, etc.

Try this query by using `PIVOT` Function:

```
select location,[a-team] as [A-team] ,[b-team] AS [B-team],[c-team] AS [C-team],[d-team] AS [D-team],[e-team] as [E-team]
from (select * from OrderingTAB) A
pivot
(Sum(pops) FOR depar in ([a-team],[b-team],[c-team],[d-team],[e-team] ) ) AS D
Order by location
```

Comment: This will pivot like most people are accustomed to and that may be what was being called for in the question. The data provided above does not look like a normal pivot, however.

Comment: This is not valid for PostgreSQL